# Python Matplotlib - how to graph top 20 of the df?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to bar graph my csv file and try to graph only the top 20 of the data, below I tried to delete data from 0 to 175 to graph the remaining data but what happens is that it only deleted the rows 0 and 175. How do I make it from 0 to 175, I tried doing 0:175 but it marked as an error

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('MAY_2021_COVID_CLEANED.csv')


df = df.drop([0,175],axis=0)

print(df)

#assigning variables
x = df['Country']
y = df['Death Count']

#Graphing
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90,fontsize=5)
plt.title("Number of Death per Country")
plt.ylabel("Number of Death")
plt.xlabel("Country")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you trying to plot the last 20 rows of the data? Or the 20 highest values from `df["Death Count"]` ? Are these the same thing?

Comment: You could sort the data frame in descending order of the number of deaths and specify the top 20 cases. For example, let's say `x=df['country'].head(20)`.

Comment: @r-beginners I think they want the last 20 rows of the df, so tail would work here. There's also [`nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)

Comment: The last 20 rows, because I already sorted it out from lowest to highest (last row is the highest) sorry for not putting it out

Comment: [`df.tail(20)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) will get you the last 20 rows

Answer (score 1):

*How do I make it from 0 to 175, I tried doing 0:175 but it marked as an error*

You might use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) built-in for this task, consider following simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
df = df.drop(range(0,5),axis=0)
print(df)
```

output

```
   value
5      5
6      6
7      7
8      8
9      9
```

Note that `range` is inclusive-exclusive therefore rows `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4` were removed - start (`0`) is inclusive, end (`5`) is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried slicing? This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('MAY_2021_COVID_CLEANED.csv')
df = df[:20]

#assigning variables
x = df['Country']
y = df['Death Count']

#Graphing
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xticks(rotation=90,fontsize=5)
plt.title("Number of Death per Country")
plt.ylabel("Number of Death")
plt.xlabel("Country")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Or df = df[-20:] to get the last 20

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just plot the last 20 rows you can use [`DataFrame.tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html)

```py
df = df.tail(20)
```

If you want the top 20 values from a series use [`DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```py
df = df.nlargest(20, "Death Count")
```